# Convert TIFF with Alpha Channel to PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, tiff, alpha-channel

I have a TIFF File that has a blue background and an Alpha Channel. I would like to save a PNG File which has the blue background transparent, using the Alpha Channel (because some pixels are not fully transparent)

I use Photoshop CS5 Standard, but I haven't found an option there. I don't want to use the Magic Wand because it struggles with half-transparent pixels and because I do have a perfect Alpha Channel.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Must the solution be within Photoshop?

Comment: @hometoast: No. It's what I use, but if there is a better/easier tool for that, I'm more than happy to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read"convert format" and I immediately think [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

```
convert input.tiff output.png
```

it's unlikely that it won't know what to do in your situation.

Comment: That worked, but I had to change the background color from blue to white, otherwise the half-transparent pixels weren't converted properly (they had a blue fringe at the edges)